# Python: how does list work within recursion

Tags: python, list, pointers, scope

I'm trying to print the path(from root to leaf node) for a binary tree. I was trying to use a list as input to record the path and return it.

However, the return value is empty, I can see the path is being generated correctly, by printing the path at the recursion function.

**Case 1:**

```
Input:
res = printPath(root, node,[]) 

Output:
res = []
```

My question is, how does list work with recursion, how does python handle the scope of it?

**Case 2:**

```
Input:
p_ = []

res = printPath(root, node, p_)

Output:
res != []
```

> also res is not equal to the final path, which inside the recursion, can you please let me know why is that. Eg, path = [3, 5], res = []

res is not empty but it will have some middle value of the recursion. I guess, in this case, the list is treated as a pointer.

If you can let me know the difference between these 2 cases, it would be great.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def printPath(self, root, node, path):
        if root:
            # print root.val, node
            if root.val == node:
                path.append(node)
                print path
                return path
            if root.left:
                path.append(root.val)
                self.printPath(root.left, node, path)
            if root.right:
                path.append(root.val)
                self.printPath(root.right, node, path)

    def lowest_main(self, root, p):
        # print root.val, p
        p_ = []
        print self.printPath(root, 5, p_)
        # print p_
```

Comment: There are a few issues with the `printPath` function you have included: `self` is not the leading argument, so you should use `printPath` instead of `self.printPath`. Second is that if you are trying to assign `res` with results of `printPath`, as implemented, `printPath` does not return a list or any value thus `res` will always equal to `None`.  Yes you can append nodes (or whatever) to `path` that is provided, and yes the same assignment will get passed as you have specified in the code you have included.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster, I tried to do the following, however the print is NONE
`p_ = []; print self.printPath(root, 5, p_)` if I print the path within the return block `if root.val == node: path.append(node);print path;return path`, I can see the correct path. do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: My apologies. I missed your `return path` statement.  However, the results of the recursive `printPath` isn't being returned which means that invocations using a root and node that are not equal will not have a return value.  This is where I was confused about when I thought your code did not have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**

Here, you are passing a list object having zero elements, as argument to the "root invocation" of `printPath()`.

Inside this invocation, that empty list can be accessed with the parameter called `path`.

During the execution of the function, that empty list would become non-empty.

But once you've exited this "root invocation" of the function, that parameter called `path`, which is referring to the (now non-empty) list, **goes out of scope**.

Now, you are left with no other variable (or name) referring to that non-empty list, so there is no way for you to actually look at the non-empty path and celebrate.

**Case 2:**

Here also, you are passing an empty list object to your "root invocation" of `printPath()`. But the difference is that even before you invoke `printPath()`, you have ensured that there is one more variable (or name) called `p_`, which is pointing to the same empty list object that you are passing to the "root invocation". As with **Case 1**, inside the invocation, the empty list object is accessed with the parameter name `path`. As with **Case 1**, this empty list will become non-empty during the execution. As with **Case 1**, when the root invocation eventually completes execution and returns control, the parameter named `path` which was pointing to the (now non-empty) list object, will go out of scope, but you are still left with one more variable called `p_`, pointing to the same (now non-empty) list object.

**Reason why print `self.printPath(root, 5, p_)` prints `None`:**

Let's take a simple tree, in which the root node has a value of 0, and the left child has a value of 5. Assume that there are no other nodes in the tree.

What happens in your root invocation of `printPath()`:

You will first check `if root.val == node`. The test will fail.

You will next check `if root.left`. The test will pass. You will enter that `if` block, append `0` to path, and **make your second invocation of `printPath()`**. Now, carefully note the fact that the second invocation is made from within the first invocation. The first invocation has not yet completed. In fact, at that instant, the first invocation as well as the second invocation are both in a state of having partially executed. Correct? And the first invocation and second invocation at **two different line numbers**. The first invocation is at the line where `printPath()` is invoked for the left child, and the first invocation is just about to start executing at the first line of `printPath()`. Correct?

What happens next?

The second invocation also checks `if root.val == node`. This time, the test succeeds, and it enters the `if` block, appends `5` to `path`, and returns `path`.

But where does this returned value go? To the place where this second invocation happened ! Which, if you remember, is another line in `printPath()`. At that line, you are invoking `printPath()`, but not capturing its return value in any variable -- you are just ignoring its return value. So, the `0 5` string returned by the second invocation is being ignored. The execution of the first invocation continues until it reaches the last line of `printPath()`. At the last line, there is no other `return` statement. So, in the absence of an explicit `return` statement, any Python function will return `None`. So, this first invocation will return `None`, to the place where your first invocation happened (I think that is in `lowest_main()`).

The first invocation is printing this `None` value.

**How to correct:**

To correct this, please change the following line:

```
self.printPath(root.left, node, path)
```

to this:

```
return self.printPath(root.left, node, path)
```

Similarly, please change the following line:

```
self.printPath(root.right, node, path)
```

to this:

```
return self.printPath(root.right, node, path)
```

Comment: Hi @fountainhead,  I tried to do the following, however, the print is NONE p_ = []; print self.printPath(root, 5, p_) if I print the path within the return block if root.val == node: path.append(node);print path;return path, I can see the correct path. do you have any idea why this is happening? Reading your post, I understand the first case, but for the second case, I'm still confused by the test case over here.

Comment: @IanZhang: From your comments, it looks like you have `printPath` as a **method** of some class, but looking at your **post**, that was not at all evident. It would be better if you could check again whether you've posted all relevant parts of the code, including the place where you actually invoke functions, your initialization of the root node, etc.

Comment: I posted the class, can you please help me check it out. Thanks

Comment: @IanZhang: Please see my answer edited with complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
>>> [].append(2)
>>> []
[]
>>> l=[]
>>> l.append(2)
>>> l
[2]
>>>
```

Because `[]` isn't stored anywhere, so won't update any variable, that's why.

`[]` would be kept in memory after `append`, but no way to access it.

Comment: Hi @U9-Forward, thanks for your answer, however, when I do the second test, I'm still getting res=[], path !=[], can you please help me out on it?